# How can I decrease the number of levels in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has a column "Days" with 4 levels (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday). I would like to have my column with only 2 levels left (Sunday, Tuesday).

I think that the fucntion I need is droplevels() however I cannot find a clear example of how to use it

```
levels(data$Days)

# this is what I have now
[1] "Sunday"      "Mondays"   "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
```

Comment: What is the rule for mapping the four current levels to only two levels?

Comment: data <- data[ ,c(1,3)]

Comment: could you give us an excerpt of your data frame and the desired result? It's not quite clear what you want.

Comment: @kashiff007: That will just select the first and third column (assuming there is a third column).

Comment: The `droplevel` function is a bookkeeping function to remove unused levels from the list of all possible levels.  If you want to reduce the dataframe to only contain the two levels then you must filter or select the rows of interest.

Comment: What I have now is 4 levels

    > levels(data$Days)
    [1] "Sunday" "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" 
I need to reduce my factor to 2 levels - e.g. only Sunday and Tuesday

Comment: `summary(data$Days)` would be useful, to know if the Monday/Tuesday levels actually occur in the data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to map Monday to Sunday and Wednesday to Tuesday, you could try:

```
levels(data$Days)[levels(data$Days) == "Monday"] <- "Sunday"
levels(data$Days)[levels(data$Days) == "Wednesday"] <- "Tuesday"
```

If you just want to remove the Monday and Wednesday levels, then try:

```
data[!(data$Days %in% c("Monday", "Wednesday")), ]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to DELETE "Monday" and "Wednesday"

Comment: @Mark I gave you an option for removing these levels.